# Parse Abnormal Date Run to List<DateTime>

Tags: c#

If I have a string with an abbreviated Short Month and comma separated date like:

```
Jul 23, 30 , Aug 06, 13, 20, 27 
    or
Jul 1, 15, 30 , Aug 14, 26 ,
```

What would be an elegant way to take this and convert it into a list of datetimes ?

Comment: in your example  how many strings are there? 2?1?

Comment: @terrybozzio there would only be one string.  I was just giving multiple examples.

Comment: I would appreciate some kind of feedback as to why this was downvoted twice.  If it is a bad question kindly let me know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) and a bit of Linq:

```
var input = "Jul 23, 30 , Aug 06, 13, 20, 27";
var dates = 
    (from Match m in Regex.Matches(input, @"(\w+)(?:[\s,]+(\d+))+")
     from Capture c in m.Groups[2].Captures
     let str = m.Groups[1].Value + " " + c.Value
     select DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MMM dd", null))
    .ToList();
```

Note that this will throw an error if there's an invalid date.